# ¿ Problema al ejecutar un .exe compilado con visual studio 2019 en c# llamándolo desde otro exe compilado por visual studio 2019 en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un reto ya que la palabra problema no me gusta mucho jijij.

He realizado un soft en c# que me hace de System try, o sea he utilizado el componente de notifYicon. Y funciona bien si le ejecuto de forma manual. He realizado un service en c# para que cuando inicie el servicio ejecute este programita try. He utilizado:

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
        {

            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ywen\";
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "YwenTry.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            myProcess.Start();

            }
```

Lo ejecuta y aparece en el administrador de tareas, pero no lo abre. Como si no interactuara con windows. Por lo que no se añade a la barra de notificaciones de windows.

Por si era problema del servicio. He creado un pequeño programita en c# para que cuando abra ese programita me ejecute el programita try. Pero me hace lo mismo, me lo ejecuta pero no me lo ejecuta bien, ya que no hace el poner el icono en la barra de notificaciones de windows o system try. Pero lo bueno es que si lo ejecuto manualmente este programita si que ejecuta bien el programita try y lo abre bien.

A ver si me podéis ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: No comprendo bien tu problema, ejecuta pero no ejecuta, el qué tiene que ejecutar y cómo?

Comment: HOola Nicolas. Perdon si no me he explicado bien.

Comment: Perdon Nicolas. Tiene que ejecutar un .exe. Este .exe es una aplicacion que he desarrollado para que se coloque como icono de notificacion de windows. Pero si lo ejecuto manualmente funciona pero si le digo a otra aplicacion desarrollada en c# que lo ejecute lo ajecuta pero no se pone en el system tray.

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a la aplicación desde un Servicio de Windows?

Comment: Buenas Victor. Lo he probado llamandolo desde varios sitios. desde un servicio que he creado en c#. También desde un aplicación de c# que cuando esta aplicación inicia que llame le llame.

Comment: Lo unico que puedo pensar es que como el servicio creado en c# es el que lo llama directamente, o este servicio llama a una aplicacion y esta aplicación llama al try. pues no tenga suficientes permisos.